# confusion about actions in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm not able to figure out whether Redux actions are synchronous or asynchronous. Consider this:

```
addBook () => {
  console.log( "current books:  ",this.props.books );

  const book = {
      id: 3,
      title: "Percy Jackson"
  };

  this.props.addBook(book); // firing off a new action [ is it synchronous or asynchronous ]

  console.log( "updated books:  ",this.props.books ); // shouldn't these be new props
}
```

From above, both `current books` and `updated books` are same, though UI is updated and I'm guessing new props from the store are also passed to this component via `mapStateToProps` method.

What am I missing?

Comment: https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions  Should explain it.

Comment: @jmargolisvt thanks. I see. It's sync in my case. Then, how come I'm getting the same values before and after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firing the *action* is synchronous.  The *reducer* however is async.  You are getting the same value before and after because it is all happening in one, synchronous render cycle.  After the reducer does its thing, your component gets updated as you've seen.  You're never going to see the `console.log` statements reflect two different states in this case.

Comment: If you were to log out the _reducer_ state, instead of the component prop, then you would see the change.